# mysql primary key as php variable and next column as string

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table with two columns, one primary key and one some data (var char). Is there a way to make php take the primary key as a variable and the next column as the string.

**Example**

Primary key= main_email, data= example@server.com.

from this PHP would do this - `$main_email = "example@server.com";`

and so on for each row, automatically.

(Database is MySQL)

Comment: Yes, but it isn't a good approach to design your database in this way, or to use dynamic variables in this way

Comment: Assuming that you've fetched your data from the database into `$row`; then `$name = $row[0]; $$name = $row[1];`.... but please rethink

Comment: I definitely agree with @MarkBaker here. You are for certain in an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) explain your problem and why you are trying this, I'm sure we will came up with a better solution.

Comment: Okay I rethought how to approach my problem and have figured out a way to solve it without involving a table. I just had to take a step back and look at it from a different perspective. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Using a string as a primary key in MySQL is usually a bad idea, and it's especially bad when it's something that could concievably change in the future as that will wreck your database relationships.